# I want to work well about "Core Data" (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, core-data, setvalue

I want to save data in core data.

But data saved is the only last data.

**I think, Important problem is the only! only! saved last one data.**

Actually I don't know English very well...

Please I want to you understand my question..

this is my code.

As I explain this code. This project has a sample.*csv*, so I separate that file. And data separated is saved by "setvalue".

**What is it problem??**

```
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString *strText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSEUCKREncoding error:nil];

    NSArray * array = [strText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSString *tempText;
    int i = 0;
    NSArray * temparray;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = [appDelegate  managedObjectContext];
    NSManagedObject *newContact;
    newContact  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:newContext];


    NSError *error;
    for(i = 1;i<[array count]-1;i++){
        tempText = [[array objectAtIndex:i]description];

        temparray = [tempText componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"];

        [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"]; 
        [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"phone"]; 
        [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"sex"]; 

        [newContext save:&error];
    }
```

Comment: are you deliberately skipping the first object in your array? You start your loop with index 1 but the first object in an array has an index of 0.

Comment: Yes, deliberately.. I solved that. :-)

Comment: okay. should have read that you parse a csv. so it's probably the table header.

Comment: Ok! I tried to read! And This is perfect output!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should put this:

```
NSManagedObject *newContact;
newContact  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
```

into the first line of the for loop

Comment: and once you did this, think about putting `[newContext save:&error];` outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the new entity outside of your loop, so you only create one new entity.  Move this bit to the top of the for loop:

```
newContact  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
```

Like:

```
for(i = 1;i<[array count]-1;i++){
    newContact  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:newContext];
    tempText = [[array objectAtIndex:i]description];

    temparray = [tempText componentsSeparatedByString:@"##"];

    [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"name"]; 
    [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"phone"]; 
    [newContact setValue:[temparray objectAtIndex:2] forKey:@"sex"]; 

    [newContext save:&error];
}
```

Comment: T^T <-- this is impressive emoticon..
You are Very Very genius. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a new contact for each temparray. So you need to move the  `newContact  = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Contacts" inManagedObjectContext:newContext];` in to the for.